# Getting exception error when trying to connect to sql server database

Tags: sql-server

I getting this error when I try to connection to sql server and I dont understand why. Here is the error:

```
Error: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' threw an exception.
Stack Trace: at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor()
             at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
```

Here is my code:

```
connectionString = "Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESSSERVER;Initial Catalog=TEST_DATABASE;User ID=USERNAME;Password=PASSWORD;"

        Dim myConnection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        myConnection.Open()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this connection string

```
connectionString = "Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESSSERVER;Initial Catalog=TEST_DATABASE;User ID=USERNAME;Password=PASSWORD;"
```

You should escape your backslash \

Anyway, examine the inner exception for more details, as they usually provide additional information

Comment: Thanks for responding. Tried the backslash and still unsuccessful.

Comment: Does the exception has an innerexception? Is so, what is the error?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the problem has anything to do with the connection string...

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922879/exception-type-initializer-for-system-data-sqlclient-sqlconnection), you probably have an error in your app.config or web.config...

**Edit**

Also, you should confirm if your code is throwing an innerexception along with the exception... Usually the real cause of the exception, will be in the innerexception...