# type initializer for System.Data.SqlClient threw an exception

Tags: c#, sqlconnection

This actually worked before but now, not.

```
string sqlConnString ="Server=server1;Database=Production;Trusted_Connection=true;User ID=User;Password=pwd"; 

        try {
            conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnString );
```

And I get the exception. (I know the connection string should be in app.config but that didn't work, either.)

Comment: What is the exception message _exactly_? Can you please be more specific?

Comment: Is the connection string still correct?

Comment: type initializer for System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection threw an exception.   If I change server to Data Source and Database to Initial Catalog, same error.

Comment: Use Namespace:  `System.Data.SqlClient` for `SqlConnection` and add a reference to assembly:  `System.Data` (in System.Data.dll)

Comment: I did both: using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration; and there is a reference to System.Data; When I try to retrieve the connection string from app.config via this: ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"].ConnectionString; I get the error "Configuration System failed to initialize" which is suspiciously similar to the other error.

Comment: @Ron It seems there is error in you app.config post code for app.config.

Comment: I had many errors; I used trusted connection and also a userID and pwd; in app.config, I had ConnectionString rather than connectionString. Now it all works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exception: type initializer for 'system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922879/exception-type-initializer-for-system-data-sqlclient-sqlconnection)

Answer (score 0):

This most likely means that there is an error in your app.config file, e.g. badly formed XML or unexpected elements. The error happens because the static fields inside SqlConnection read from app.config to determine trace detail level as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254503.aspx

(this question is a duplicate of [Exception: type initializer for 'system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922879/exception-type-initializer-for-system-data-sqlclient-sqlconnection))

Answer (score -1):

Remove the underscore between Trusted and Connection.