# Invoke-Sqlcmd : The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.InOutOfProcHelper' threw an exception

Tags: sql-server, powershell, invoke-sqlcmd

I'm trying to execute SQL Query from Powershell.

**My Script:**

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "select 'Y' from sys.databases" -ServerInstance .
```

**Error :**

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd : The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.InOutOfProcHelper' threw an exception.
At C:\temp\Untitled5.ps1:2 char:1
+ Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "select 'Y' from sys.databases" -ServerInstance  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (.:PSObject) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], TypeInitializationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExecutionFailed,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6922879/5894421

Comment: Check log files.  See my response here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76090242/sql-collection-working-in-ise-but-not-with-powershell-exe

Comment: Could be any number of things from client authentication to server authentication. A more detailed exception with stack trace would be helpful. Given you seem to be in PowerShell 7+ as the exception mentions `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` does adding `-Encrypt None` to command change things? What if you change the query to `select 'Y' as [SomeColumnNameHere] from sys.databases`?

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was because the version of the module installed was certainly buggy.

`Install-Module sqlserver` installed the 21.1.1 ; I had to uninstall it and reinstall the 21.1.18256 :

```
Uninstall-Module -Name SqlServer
Install-Module SqlServer -RequiredVersion 21.1.18256 -Force
```

All is OK now...

(to know the actual version of your installed modules, use `Get-InstalledModule`)