# SQL collection working in ISE but not with powershell.exe

Tags: sql, powershell

I'm trying to exectute a powershell script as a task manager function that writes the return of an sql query to a CSV file on the local server.

I build the script in Powershell ISE running as a non Admin user and it works perfectly, however when I try and run it as a Task Schduler script it just stays in a 'Running' state.

When I attempt to run the same script in a CMD window by passing powershell.exe c:\temp\dbExport.ps1 Powershell throws an error with the script, the same is true when running this within powershell, the error is;

```
Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "The SelectCommand property has not been initialized before calling 'Fill'."
At C:\temp\dbExport.ps1.ps1:38 char:1
+ $rowCount = $adapter.Fill($dataset)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException
 
Export-Csv : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
At C:\temp\dbExport.ps1:44 char:24
+ $dataset.Tables.rows | Export-Csv -Path $tempFile -NoTypeInformation
+                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Export-Csv], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand
```

The Powershell script i'm attempting to execute is;

```
# Variables for server, database and query
$server   = 'dbhost1.local'
$database = 'test'
$query    = "SELECT * FROM ProdDB1"
$tempFile ="c:\temp\temp.csv"
$ctpmCsv = "C:\temp\Mapping.csv"
# Set up the objects needed
$connection = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$adapter    = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $command
$dataset    = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.DataSet

# Set the connection string (using single sign on) and open the connection
$connection.ConnectionString = "Server=$server;Database=$database;Trusted_Connection=True;"
$connection.Open()

# Create a command object and assign the query
$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $query

# Fill the dataset and count the rows returned at the same time
$rowCount = $adapter.Fill($dataset)

# Since the dataset is populated we can now close the connection
$connection.Close()

# Return the results
$dataset.Tables.rows | Export-Csv -Path $tempFile -NoTypeInformation
(Get-Content -LiteralPath $tempFile | Select-Object -Skip 1) -replace '"', '' | Set-Content -LiteralPath $ctpmCsv
```

As stated previously, i've attempted to run this in powershell, it fails with the above error and however it works perfectly within Powershell ISE.

Any suggestions you might have towards a resolution to my problem would be very well recieived.

Thanks in advance.

**Solution:**

I'm adding this to help people out in future, I can't explain why running this in ISE worked when it didn't when passing as an argument against powershell.exe but the below code change resolved it.

Hopefully this will help someone in the future and avoid further passive aggressive comments from users;

```
# Variables for server, database and query
$server   = 'dbhost1.local'
$database = 'test'
$query    = "SELECT * FROM ProdDB1"
$tempFile ="c:\temp\temp.csv"
$ctpmCsv = "C:\temp\Mapping.csv"
# Set up the objects needed
$connection = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$adapter    = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $command
$dataset    = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.DataSet

# Set the connection string (using single sign on) and open the connection
$connection.ConnectionString = "Server=$server;Database=$database;Trusted_Connection=True;"
$connection.Open()

# Create a command object and assign the query
$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $query

# Fill the dataset and count the rows returned at the same time
$rowCount = $adapter.Fill($dataset)

# Since the dataset is populated we can now close the connection
$connection.Close()

# Return the results
$dataset.Tables.rows | Export-Csv -Path $tempFile -NoTypeInformation

# Parsing the return to remove headers and additional quotations.
(Get-Content -LiteralPath $tempFile | Select-Object -Skip 1) -replace '"', '' | Set-Content -LiteralPath $ctpmCsv
```

Comment: Here: `$adapter    = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $command` , variable `$command` has not been initialized

Comment: The error usually indicates the Adapter is null.  So most likely the credentials are bad.  PS does run with Admin unless you right click PS shortcut and select Run As Admin.  Best way of debugging issue is to use SQL Server Management Studio and check log file in the explorer under Management.  Compare the user/group that is used when working and not working to verify the same group is being used.  Your code is using Windows Credentials.  Also look at login windows for SSMS and check that Windows Credentials are used and the Server\Instance is same as in your connection string.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. (But is this really related to the SQL _language_?)

Comment: The request doesn't appear to be hitting the sql server, if I attempt to make a request directly to the server using another script I've written and add invalid credentials it appears in the logs, however the above script doesn't have anything in the logs so I think it is something to do with the $command initialisation but if I try and init $command before I call the adaptor it still works in ISE and not in PS.

Comment: As @Theo already mentioned (why don't people ever read and action comments), at line 9 `$adapter    = New-Object......` you haven't yet defined `$command`

Comment: Hi @Theo I have read the comment.  However if i try an initialise $command before I do the adaptor it still fails with the same error.  As per my inital post, this is working in ISE I just don't understand why it's not in PS.

Comment: @Foolishstar - as a test , try restarting your ISE session and see if it still works. You might have a variable hanging around from a previous version of your code that allows it to work in the *current* ISE session, but fails when you run the script in a clean PowerShell session. If that's the case it will also fail after you restart the ISE - it won't solve your problem but it might eliminate some of the confusion about why the script is working in the ISE...

Comment: It would be great if you could post the solution in more detail to help others.